# python 27 input string using tkSimpleDialog

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, input

I am using a simple gui with Tkinter to control my program on Windows 7 with python27. Furthermore I want to avoid to many additional packages because I will freeze the program later and I want to avoid problems with "exotic" packages.

In one case I have to change a sensorname and I am using a simple function like this:

```
def change_sensorname():
    new_sensorname = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Sensorname", "Please input the new sensorname")
```

It works fine but how can I limit the accepted characters in this case? I want to catch the wrong strings before the input window is closed. If this is not possible I just open another one.

I want to limit the maximum length and I also want to limit the different characters. For example only 5 characters and only the letters from A-Z and "_".

Is there an easy way to filter this? For example if you use askinteger, you can set the min and maxvalue, but for the askstring there is no certain restriction implemented.

Cheers Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [askstring does not have such functionality](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm), so do a loop:

```
def meets_sensorname_criteria(sensorname):
    max_len = 10
    restricted_chars = ('@', '!', '?')
    return (len(sensorname) < max_len 
            and not any((char in sensorname) for char in restricted_chars))

def change_sensor_name():
    new_sensorname = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Sensorname", "Please input the new sensorname")
    while not meets_sensorname_criteria(new_sensorname):
        # Some warning alert here to explain expected input might be good
        new_sensorname = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Sensorname", "Please input the new sensorname")
```

**Edit:**
The alternative really does look like it's rolling your own Dialog class.  However, if the [source for `tkSimpleDialog`](http://bugs.python.org/file22286/tkSimpleDialog.py) is any indication, it's going to be quite a few lines of code to get a similar set of functionality by inheriting `Dialog` and replicating/modifying `_QueryDialog`, `_QueryString` and `askstring`.

You *can* try inheriting from `_QueryString` directly but can't say I recommend it.

Comment: thx for the help! I thought maybe there is another option except an infinite loop. Thx for the example, I think everybody gets the idea, but there are a few syntax mistakes in.

Comment: Thanks, edited (at least the ones found).  The other alternative is to roll your own widget of course (perhaps inheriting tkSimpleDialog).

Comment: but is there no other option to catch this? Another problem is that you can not cancel the input or do I get this wrong?

Comment: You're right about not being able to `Cancel`, you may need to just duplicate the assignment outside the while loop to prevent this.  Let me see if I can write something up about rolling your own widget (overwriting the .validate method)

Comment: i formed it into a try statement and in case of the specific error, in this case TypeError, I just cancel and close the window

Comment: Ah makes sense, that sounds like a solution